# How to store and retrieve objects in firebase for Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a user class. And the user class has a arraylist of users called followers. When i try to upload a user object (with a few users in the followers arraylist for this user object) Firebase isn't able to do it and my program crashes...I can't figure how to store and retrieve my own objects that have in them other customized objects.

So the main error i get is:

```
unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daprlabs.swipedeck/com.daprlabs.swipedeck.ActivityCenter}: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
```

Here is my java code.

EDITED: adding @exclude, but still doesn't work...

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRef = new Firebase("Fire base reference...");
        dummyUser();
    }

    private void dummyUser()
    {
        //Andie <- Chris <- Qamar
        mainDummyUser = new User();
        mainDummyUser.setName("Chris");
        mainDummyUser.setLocation("Deutchland");
        mainDummyUser.setDummyImage(R.drawable.chris);
        //Second Dummy
        User secondDummy = new User();
        secondDummy.setName("Andie");
        secondDummy.setLocation("Germany");
        secondDummy.setDummyImage(R.drawable.andie);
        secondDummy.addtoFollowers(mainDummyUser);

        mainDummyUser.addtoFollowers(secondDummy);

        //Add users to Firebase
        mRef.child("users").child("Dummy User 1").setValue(mainDummyUser);


    }
```

Here is my user class, pretty simple.

```
public class User
{
    private String userName;
    private int userID;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userProfilePicture;
    private ArrayList<CityFolders> userFolders = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructor
    public User()
    {
        setDummyUserID();
    }
    public void addtoFollowers(User user)
    {
        userFollowers.add(user);
    }
    public void setLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public void setDummyImage(int image)
    {
        this.dummyImage = image;
    }
   
     public void setDummyUserID()
    {
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        userID = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
    }
    //Getter
    public String getUserName()
    {
       return userName;
    }


    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }
    public int getUserID()
    {
        return userID;
    } 
    @Exclude
    public ArrayList<UserFinal> getUserFollowers()
    {
       return userFollowers;
    }
    //Goes on...
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
08-24 19:07:26.549 23384-23384/com.daprlabs.swipedeck E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.daprlabs.swipedeck, PID: 23384
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daprlabs.swipedeck/com.daprlabs.swipedeck.ActivityCenter}: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                         Caused by: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
                                                                            at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:357)
                                                                            at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:248)
                                                                            at com.daprlabs.swipedeck.ActivityCenter.dummyUser(ActivityCenter.java:165)
                                                                            at com.daprlabs.swipedeck.ActivityCenter.onCreate(ActivityCenter.java:122)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowing"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.daprlabs.swipedeck.Globals.User["userFollowers"]->java.util.Arra
08-24 19:07:26.577 23384-23394/com.daprlabs.swipedeck W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.173ms
```

Comment: Do you need the back-link from the followers to the followed user? As the error message indicates this creates an infinite chain of objects...

Comment: No, because every user also has a arraylist called userFollowing. So the followers will each have their own arrayList called "userFollowing", which in this case for each of the followers, their followingUser array would have the mainDummyUser

Comment: Then just delete the back-link :) Or exclude the property like I outlined in my answer.

Comment: so you mean delete the getUserFollowing() method?

Comment: And maybe the whole property if you don't need it. Or just Exclude it from perisistance

Answer (score 1):

How about to use not User but UserID ?
Like

```
    private void dummyUser()
    {
        mainDummyUser = new User();
        mainDummyUser.setName("Chris");
        mainDummyUser.setLocation("Deutchland");

        User secondDummy = new User();
        secondDummy.setName("Andie");
        secondDummy.setLocation("Germany");

        secondDummy.addFollowerUserIDs(mainDummyUser.getUserID());
        mainDummyUser.addFollowerUserIDs(secondDummy.getUserID());
        //Add users to Firebase
        mRef.child("users").child(mainDummyUser.getUserID()).setValue(mainDummyUser);
        mRef.child("users").child(secondDummy.getUserID()).setValue(secondDummy);
    }
```

and

```
public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String location;
    private String userID;
    private ArrayList<String> FollowerUserIDs = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public User()
    {
        setDummyUserID();
    }
    public void addFollowerUserIDs(String userID)
    {
        FollowerUserIDs.add(userID);
    }

    public void setLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public void setDummyImage(int image)
    {
    // this.dummyImage = image;
    }

    public void setDummyUserID()
    {
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        userID = String.valueOf(randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(1000000));
    }

    public void setUserID()
    {
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        userID = String.valueOf(randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(1000000));
    }
    //Getter
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }
    public String getUserID()
    {
        return userID;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFollowerUserIDs()
    {
        return FollowerUserIDs;
    }
}
```

Also, your sample code is

```
public class User
{
    private String userName;
    private int userID;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userProfilePicture;
    private ArrayList<CityFolders> userFolders = new ArrayList<>();.
```

but it should be

```
public class User
{
    private String userName;
    private int userID;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userProfilePicture;
    private ArrayList<User> userFollowers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @Seriyo Thank you Seiryo. I implemented with the userId as well. And it works. So instead of just querying the user directly, what I can do is make a firebase reference directly to that user id and grab it like so: `Firebase referenceToUser2 = mRef.child(String.valueOf(getUserID)); `

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Exclude` to the getter method of the `userFollowing` property. This should break the infinite loop issue.

```
@Exclude
public User getUserFollowing()
```

This works if you always update the user in this way (having a user and his followers). It might be an issue if you want to update a user that is a follower directly.

Comment: So I tried that. I put it at getUserFollowing, and every where else and it still doesn't work. After serious testing I realized that I cannot put mainDummyUser in secondDummy's FollowersArray and then put secondDummy in mainDummy's followers Array. An object cannot possess itself. And I cannot for the life of me fix it....

Comment: If you still get the same error even if you put @Exclude at the getter something else is wrong. Which version of Firebase are you using on Android?

Comment: This is the current firebase version:  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'

Comment: so if I DO NOT put mainDummyUser in secondDummy's follower's array, and I put mainDummyUser into firebase it works. But as soon as mainDummyUser has secondDummy which has mainDummyUser it keeps on crashing. I put "@exclude" in the getter but that didn't do anything? Could you possibly test it our quickly with the same kind of set up and see if it works and post it?

My version of firebase is: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'

Comment: so I edited the code above, that is currently what i have done. and nothing is working.

Comment: Also, does anything in my security rules or anything in my firebase console need to be adjusted? Because write now my secruity is open to everything.

Comment: so it turns out my firebase was outdated and it accepts `@JsonIgnore` and not `@Exclude`. So is there a way to add mainDummy to secondDummy's followers and then adding that to mainDummy's follwers? without having my app crash and storing them in firebase? Because `@jsonIgnore` does not let me store secondDummy in mainDummy's followers array

Comment: Can you please update the stack trace? I'm quite sure it's a (if slightly) different error now